# How can I maintain styles upon pressing Enter in Jodit text editor?

Tags: typescript, jodit

After applying styles (Bold, Italic, etc..), pressing enter creates a new line and the styles have been removed. How can I prevent this and carry over the styles to the new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `enter` key to `br` in the Jodit config.

```
const editor = new Jodit('#element', { enter: 'br' })
```

Hope that helps!

**Reference:**
https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/options/enter/